# Force table to display 5 rows with or without data

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, report

I have to display a table of 5 rows fetching from MySQL database using PHP. From the code below, if I have 3 rows in database, it will display only 3 rows. But, I need to display 5 rows with 2 empty rows along with 3 fetched rows. If there are no records found in the database, I should display 5 empty rows. I need your help on that.

**Note:** I am generating a report using PHP and MySQL. From the above method, I can fix the table height and so report will generate without any overlaps.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
$select= "select * from table where id=1";

$select2= mysql_query($select);
$select3= mysql_num_rows($select2);

$row_count = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){ 
?>
     <tr>

                <td ><?php echo $row_count;?>.</td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['phone_number']; ?></td>

     </tr> 
<?php $row_count++;
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already counting the `$row_count` variable, you can add simple `while` loop, like this:

```
<?
while($row_count < 5){ 
?>
     <tr>

                <td >&nbsp;</td>
                <td >&nbsp;</td>
                <td >&nbsp;</td>
                <td >&nbsp;</td>

     </tr> 
<?php $row_count++;
}?>
```

[What is `&nbsp;`? Is it needed?](http://www.sightspecific.com/%7Emosh/www_faq/nbsp.html)

Also check the @paxdiablo's answer about `limit 5` option for your query.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
<?php
$select= "select * from table where id=1";

$select2= mysql_query($select);
$select3= mysql_num_rows($select2);

$row_count = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){ 
?>
     <tr>

                <td ><?php echo $row_count;?>.</td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $rows['phone_number']; ?></td>

     </tr> 
<?php $row_count++;
}
if ($row_count < 5){
    for ($i=1; $i <= (5-$row_count); $i++){
?>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have two distinct problems (albeit related).

If you only want five rows even if your query returns twenty, you can either use the control variable `$row_count` to only output rows for the first five, or (preferably) just add `limit 5` on to your query to get five rows or less.

The second problem is what to do if it returns less than five rows. In that case, use the control variable to output blank rows, something like adding the following to the end:

```
<?php
    while ($row_count < 5) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> 
<?php
        $row_count++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){ 
?>
 <tr>

            <td ><?php echo $row_count;?>.</td>
            <td ><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $rows['phone_number']; ?></td>

</tr> <?php }
if($select3<5){
for($i=1;$i<5-$select3;$i++){?>
     <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
</tr> 
<?php  }
}
```